# How may i create Email accounts on my own server and receive emails to that account using PHP?

Tags: php, email

I can easily send emails from my script using following code:

```
<?php mail("receiver1,receiver2,...","subject","body","From: info@mydomain.com") ?>
```

Am i able to create an email account on my server such as info@mydomain.com and read email on that account using PHP without manually going to cpanel and create the account there?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @SuperDJ you sure bout that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cPanel's JSON API to create and manage your email accounts. It's too difficult to walk you through so I'll just leave this here. Good luck.

http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2014/07/using-cpanels-json-api-with-php-curl-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course! Everyting is possible! Just Google it.

And take a look at this : http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/cpanel-create-email-account.php

or : http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2014/07/using-cpanels-json-api-with-php-curl-to.html

Comment: This doesn't usually work. At least it never has on any cPanel I've ever used because the login credentials need to be POSTed. The link in my answer explains it.

Comment: LOL I wrote that lib, so if you like it, please check my answer so I can get some sweet points.

Comment: @Adelphia Hahaha,I don't why i have gotten mixed today. (; I just took a quick look at it and i taught that was just a copy from cPanel Docs website.